# previous page moves up after visting a new page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm building an ionic app and there is a back link that always links users back to the previous page. what i've noticed is when the user scrolls to the middle or the buttom of a page and click on a new url and then uses the back button on the url to come back to the previous page, the page will automatically start from the top again. When i test on pc, the state maintains its state but when i deployed to an android phone i found this happening?

JS

```
.controller('back_ctrl', function($scope, $ionicHistory) 
{
   $scope.goBack=function()
    {
        $ionicHistory.goBack();                      //This doesn't work
        //window.history.back();                     //This works
        //alert('goBackHandler called. Did it work?'); //For testing
    };
})
```

HTML

```
 <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
   <button class="button button-icon icon ion-chevron-left" ng-controller="back_ctrl" ng-click="goBack()"> </button> 
   </ion-nav-buttons>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you're trying to create controller for this one.. Ionic gave this feature as default.

Could you try this out:

```
    <!-- Header Start -->
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">

            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <i class="fa fa-navicon"></i>                    
            </ion-nav-buttons>
            <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
            <h1 class="title"></h1>
            <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>              
            </ion-nav-buttons>

        </ion-nav-bar>                        
        <!-- Header End -->
```

So, The `ion-nav-back-button` will appear when the user is able to go back in the current navigation stack. By default, the markup of the back button is automatically built using platform-appropriate defaults (iOS back button icon on iOS and Android icon on Android).

Additionally, the button is automatically set to `$ionicGoBack()` on click/tap. By default, the app will navigate back one view when the back button is clicked.